# Road trip planner online

Tags: online-resources, transportation, road-trips, maps

I'm considering a cross-country (USA) road trip sometime in the near future -- the consideration of it keeps me alive until I can get out on the road... I messed around on Google Maps, but it stopped letting me add destinations after the "X"th one (or the 24th numerically)

Has anyone used a good ONLINE service that allows for many destinations (over 75)?

If not, looks like I'll be taking it back to the paper giants and some trusty, 'ole needles to mark!

Comment: How about https://www.tripit.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the myscenicdrives.com Road Trip Planner which allows an unlimited number of stops, provides you with an estimate of your fuel costs and allows you to manage your budget, divides your trip into manageable days, share with friends, and much more.  Once you are ready to hit the road, print the trip or export it to your GPS.  Best of all its all free with a free account: https://www.myscenicdrives.com/road-trip-planner

Answer (score 4):

I used [Tripline](http://www.tripline.net/) to show where I've been on recent trips. Again it's point A to B, but at least you can easily share it on facebook or a blog. For example, my [2010 South American journey map](http://www.marksmayo.com/south-american-journey/) is embedded on my blog.

They are in beta and seem to be adding new features fairly recently. I'd love them to add the ability to show two people travelling at once - like if you were racing someone across Europe, showing where you each were at diff times on the same map would look awesome.

Comment: Wow! Not exactly what I was looking for, but that is an awesome site. Definitely going to be using that on my blog when this trip happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

https://roadtrippers.com/

While this question is a little old it demanded an updated answer.

[image]

Comment: I just discovered this site myself a couple weeks ago, it is great! Have an upvote.