# Road trip planning tool

Tags: usa, planning, road-trips

I want to make a road trip through the USA with two friends.

Are there any good tools that help us planning this?

Like marking spots on a USA-Map, attach pictures and comments, draw lines from one marker to another and so on. It would also be nice if you could see who did what (write a comment, attach a picture...) and maybe even support email notifications.

So far, I only found this one:
https://www.myscenicdrives.com/road-trip-planner

EDIT:
Yes, I saw [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7813/road-trip-planner-online), but I think my question is more specific (working in a group, augmenting markers with pictures, comments etc.) :) Also I included one of the answers (myscenicdrives.com) in my question to emphasize, that I'd like something more "rich" :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Road trip planner online](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7813/road-trip-planner-online)

Answer (score 3):

Got a Google account? Create a shared document. There are even templates already created to help you (see [Road Trip Calculator Template](https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0Ag5aveu4M6rydDF4Qm1wazJnMHRKYWJQM2stdjBfQ2c&mode=public&pli=1#))

Answer (score 3):

If you go to maps.google.com you have the options to make maps and collaborate with others. After you are logged in just click on "My Places" on the left column and then you can create a the map you want. If you are using the new google maps then you have to click the settings on the top right corner and then click on "My Places".

I have made several maps this way for my travels and share the results with people I am traveling with. Here is an example of a custom map by someone.

http://goo.gl/maps/Rh4W5

**EDIT:**

Here is a demo map I made that might illustrate things better.

http://goo.gl/maps/cQXB2

I clearly have comments, markers and I have inserted pictures. The pictures have to be links though so you need to upload them to a web folder like Google Drive or Picasa where you can directly link the pics. This isn't a collaboration but there is a collaborate button when you make your own map so other people can join in. The icons I used are stock icons that come with google maps but you can actually upload your own custom icons if you want.

When you collaborate it will also say who did the last edit and who placed what marker.

Comment: Actually after doing a little searching you can add pictures as long as it's a link.

Comment: I did not know that - very nice!